# ORACLE - error PLS-00103 in a procedure

Tags: sql, database, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I wrote this simple procedure following ORACLE Documentation in order to practice with PL/SQL:

```
create procedure BADGE_PROCEDURE (badges NUMBER) AS  
  loops NUMBER;  
BEGIN  
  loops := badges;  
  loops := loops - 1;  
  BEGIN LOOP  
    insert into BADGE values (BADGE_ID_SEQUENCE.nextval, 'prova', 'prova', '01-JAN-01');       
    loops := loops - 1;  
    EXIT WHEN loops < 0;  
  END LOOP;  
END;  
/
```

This is my BADGE table:

```
CREATE TABLE BADGE  
(badge_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,   
name VARCHAR(20),   
surname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,   
birthday DATE);
```

Finally this is my sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE BADGE_ID_SEQUENCE   
start with 1      
increment by 1    
nocache   
nocycle;
```

However, the procedure compiles with the following error:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
11/5     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting
        one of the following:
        ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
        null pragma raise return select update while with
        <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
        <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock
        insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
        merge pipe purge
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `begin loop` should be simply `loop` (no `begin`), if I remember correctly..

Comment: You're right! My mistake

Comment: Also, if you are adding a date into a DATE column / variable, please, please, PLEASE convert it into a DATE first. At present, you're trying to insert a string, which forces Oracle to use the default nls_date_format parameter for your session. This may differ for other sessions and your code may error. Far better to be explicit and either use the date literal format of `DATE '2001-01-01'` or use to_date, e.g.: `to_date('01/01/2001', 'dd/mm/yyyy')`. Note that years have four digits, not two - why make the db guess when you can provide exact information up-front?

Comment: Right, thank you for the advice, I will keep in mind it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [syntax for a loop](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/basic_loop_statement.htm#LNPLS01328) is `LOOP ... END LOOP;` without the `BEGIN`.

```
create procedure BADGE_PROCEDURE (badges NUMBER) AS  
  loops NUMBER;  
BEGIN  
  loops := badges;  
  loops := loops - 1;  
  LOOP  
    insert into BADGE values (BADGE_ID_SEQUENCE.nextval, 'prova', 'prova', DATE '2001-01-01');       
    loops := loops - 1;  
    EXIT WHEN loops < 0;  
  END LOOP;  
END;  
/
```

However, an even simpler version would be:

```
create procedure BADGE_PROCEDURE (badges NUMBER) AS  
BEGIN  
  FOR loops IN 1 .. badges LOOP  
    insert into BADGE values (BADGE_ID_SEQUENCE.nextval, 'prova', 'prova', DATE '2001-01-01');       
  END LOOP;  
END;  
/
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for!

Comment: @Boneist Fixed to use Date literals - TBH I hadn't even looked at what was being inserted (but since I normally pick other people up on inserting dates I ought to have looked).

Comment: @MT0 *{:-) no worries; happens to the best of us!

Answer (score 2):

Your loop syntax is wrong..

Just do

```
             LOOP  
                     insert into BADGE values (BADGE_ID_SEQUENCE.nextval, 'prova', 'prova', '01-JAN-01');       
                     loops := loops - 1;  
                     EXIT WHEN loops < 0;  
             END LOOP;
```

Here is an [example](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/controlstatements.htm#LNPLS402) from oracle docs.